# Как изменить шрифт (отдельный файл в папке font) для TextView, через XML

Tags: java, android, шрифты

Я использовал `android:fontFamily="@font/font_name"`, (перед этим создал папку в каталоге res).

В окне превю шрифт отображается нормально но на телефоне не изменяется.

Попытался установить шрифт программно, сработало:

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.font_name);
textview.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если напрямую через разметку, то аттрибут

```
  <TextView
android:fontFamily="@font/font_awesome"
/>
```

Если через стили, то

```
<TextView
style="@style/textMainTitle"
/>
```

и в папке стилей:

```
    <style name="textMainTitle">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Проблема в том что, в окне preview, шрифт отображается, но когда я приложение проверяю на телефоне то шрифт стоит стандартный. (Если нужно скину фотки кода, preview, экран телефона)